# Android Market, Search results position Mystery

Tags: android, search, position, google-play

How is an app's position in the Android Market search results determined? Is it as mysterious and complex as Google Web search results?

We obviously don't want to change any words in our app's title or description that would hurt our position.

Same question applies for not only search results, but when clicking on a Category in the Android Market. How is the order of the list determined?

Hopefully someone here can help. I would think that Google would have published some guidelines at least that could help, but I haven't found anything yet.

Comment: +1 Great Q.  I want to know the answer, as a consumer!

Comment: Rating and number of sales seem to be less of a factor than I would have thought. My app has 4.3 star rating and sales of over 20,000 which is pretty rare. Not even many free apps compete with those numbers.  Yet we consistently get pushed down in search results by what looks like re-released versions of apps that nobody is buying and have poor ratings. 

Post your observations here!!!

Comment: Paul G, what is your total/active install ratio?  I think that has a big impact.

Answer (score 2):

My theory is that the total to active install ratio is very important.  So, the obvious approach is to target customers who don't know how to uninstall apps :)

Answer (score 1):

*Search result ranking*— there is purposefully no publicized documentation, to minimize the chances  of gaming the system.

*Category top paid/free ranking*— again, there is purposefully no publicized documentation, but it's a combination of several metrics, several of which quantify application 'popularity.'